# A simple example using html, javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I'm starting with javascript, websockets and jQuery developing a simple example. In the html page I only have a button, that, when pressed, has to send its state (ON/OFF for instance). In index html, I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
    <title>First App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/APP.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <div id='hello_message'>
                Connecting...
        </div>
        <button id='state'>Turn on</button>
        <div id='off'>OFF</div>
        <div id='on'>ON</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My intention is to open a websocket between the client and the server when the page is loaded, and keep it open for any information to be sent between both of them. To this end, I have the following file containing the js code (APP.js):

```
window.onload = APPStart;

// Page onload event handler
function APPStart() {
    state = false;

    if ("WebSocket" in window)
    {
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://10.30.0.142:8020");

        ws.onopen = function()
        {
            alert ("Connected");
            $('#hello_message').text("Connected");
        };

        ws.onmessage = function (evt)
        {
            var received_msg = evt.data;
        };

        ws.onclose = function()
        {
             alert("Connection is closed...");
        };

        window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
             socket.close();
        };
    }

    else
    {
        // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
        alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
    }}
```

Now, every time someone clicks on button, I would like to execute the following code:

```
        // program checks if led_state button was clicked
        $('#state').click(function() {
            alert ("click");
            // changes local led state
            if (led_state == true){
                $('#on').hide();
                $('#off').show();
                state = false;
                ws.send("ON");
            }
            else{
                $('#off').hide();
                $('#on').show();
                state = true;
                ws.send("OFF");
            }
        });
```

I've tried to put this part of the code inside the function APPStart, but it doesn't work. I also suspect that jQuery is not working either since messages are not updated. Any suggestion to make it work?

Comment: Well `ws` is defined inside of `APPStart` so did you add the onclick inside of APPStart?

Comment: Have you some errors in your client console ?
Could you provide your server implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. The code works, the problem was in the cache of the browser. Once I noticed it, I cleaned the cache and everything started to work. Silly me.